# ItemContainerStyle for RibbonGroup

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to bind a RibbonGroup and a couple of RibbonButtons to my viewmodel with the following xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonGroup}" x:Key="RibbonGroupStyle">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource RibbonButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Buttons}" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonButton}" x:Key="RibbonButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Label" Value="{Binding Header}" />
</Style>
```

This gives me the following error, which I can understand, but how do I properly bind the Label of the RibbonButton to my viewmodel?

```
A style intended for type 'RibbonButton' cannot be applied to type 'RibbonControl'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place one style inside the other and apply it to every button:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonGroup}" x:Key="RibbonGroupStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ribbon:RibbonButton}">
            <Setter Property="Label" Value="{Binding Header}" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Buttons}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Ok, but what would the best way be to apply it to every button?

Comment: If you don\`t specify Style key then it should apply to all controls of this type.

Comment: So I realized that the problem is that when I bind my list of ribbon button view model objects to the ItemsSource of my RibbonGroup they are created as RibbonControls and not RibbonButtons, how do I control that? I think I'm missing something fundamental in my binding.

Comment: Apparently `RibbonButtons` are wrapped with `RibbonControls`. But code from my answer should work in this situation anyway (except if every `RibbonButton` has explicitly set style).

Comment: I added a simple DataTemplate containing simply "<ribbon:RibbonButton />" to the ItemTemplate of my RibbonGroup style and that seems to work in my case.